# Is there a way to create a masking policy accessible across all databases and schemas in Snowflake?

Tags: security, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, policy, masking, pii

I created a masking policy that I can apply across different schemas and databases. However, unless I recreate the masking policy in each database schema combination it won't let me apply the policy. It would throw
`Masking policy 'DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.POLICY_NAME' does not exist or not authorized.`
Until i create the masking policy with that database and schema selected.

Comment: Yes. It's actually best practice that you keep utility-type content in a separate db schema so it can be centrally managed. That said policy can then be applied to any table any where as long as you have defined your RBAC + privileges well. That same utility area could also house other content that you could centrally manage, like functions, stored procedures and so on.

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake do you mean that i have the masking policy AND the PII tables in the same db/schema?

Comment: in that case how can i use the masking policy defined in a separate db and apply it to columns in my prod db? It keeps throwing that the masking policy does not exist

Comment: As Eric states below, in Snowflake you have the flexibility to define these objects in the same area or in seperate areas; access of those objects is controlled by RBAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kyle you simply define your masking policy in a separate DB/Schema, and you can reference it from any other DBs/Schemas.

For example, you create policy_db.policy_schema.email_mask, then you can reference this policy using the absolute path in your apply query.

```
alter table if exists user_info 
  modify column email set masking policy policy_db.policy_schema.email_mask;
```

The policy does not have to be under the same DB/Schema where the table you want to apply sits under.